# freeform - Custom field, date format

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

We have a need for a date input.
I want to use jquery UI date picker, and I'm building a third_party plugin for freeform to use to create dates, with options for start and end dates selectable by the end user.
These I'll pass to the front end no prob.

It's getting a little convoluted and It dawned on me that there might be an existing option out there? I can't be the first person ever to want to use dates in freeform... can I?

i'll carry on development, but if there are any pointers out there, I'll listen.

If I hear nothing I'll keep on developing and share my plugin later...

Cheers..

Comment: Have you considered just using a text field in Freeform, which will store the formatted date values submitted by your front-end date picker fields?

Comment: I did.. but that's no fun :) I want to use query date picker (or something similar). I want to give the admin options to say 'ignore weekends' or 'exclude public holidays' making those options not select-able to the end user. Naturally I'll have to do the same validation on the back end, but I think it'll be a good addition to the module. I'll publish wen done..

Comment: Did you ever make that date-picker for Free Form? I was going to use one. :D

Answer (score 3):

I might be missing the goal here (you mentioned a plugin so this might be too simple), but you can very easily add a jQuery UI `Datepicker` widget to any custom form field in Freeform Pro. Just create a custom text field in the Freeform Pro control panel, lets call it **Start Date**:

Field Type: `text`

Field Label: `Start Date`

Auto-generated Field Name: `start_date`

Fully generated freeform field `id`: `freeform_start_date`

Then in your form template all you need to add is the following jQuery code (assuming you have already loaded jQuery and jQuery UI JS and CSS):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#freeform_start_date').datepicker();
</script>
```

You can add all the jQuery UI bells and whistles wherever you instantiate it.

Then the relevant part of my Freeform template becomes (here I have two Datepicker widgets):

```
{exp:freeform:composer form_name="myform" return="success"}
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Make text fields jQuery UI Datepicker Widgets
    // Add the ability to change Month and Year with built-in jQuery UI dropdowns
    $('#freeform_start_date, #freeform_end_date').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true
    });
</script>
```

I hope that helps you and future SO viewers.